# Assign to variable after then catch

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web3js

I have a $watchCollection in angularJS that calls the function `getBalance(addr)` in the listener.

```
$scope.$watchCollection('settings',
  function() {
    for (i = 0; i < $scope.settings['accounts'].length; i++) {
      var bal = $scope.getBalance($scope.settings['accounts'][i]);
      console.log(bal);
    }
  }
);
```

The function getBalance is defined as follows:

```
$scope.getBalance = function(addr) {
  var balance;
  if ($scope.settings.contract !== null) {
    $scope.settings.contract.deployed().then(function(deployed) {
      return deployed.balanceOf(addr);
    }).then(function(res) {
       balance = res.toNumber();
       console.log(balance);
       return balance;
    }).catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err.message);
    });
  }
  return balance;
};
```

The problem is that in `then`, the `balance` variable is printed correctly however, in $watchCollection, return is `undefined`.

The problem should be because JS keeps executing without waiting for a result therefore the variable is read as `undefined` however, how do I have to change these two snippets of code in order to get the result when ready and append it to `$scope.balance`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to change async code to sync code, which you can't really do. You need to carry the promise all the way through, in both.

Instead of setting `balance` to a variable and returning that variable, return the promise itself, then use `then` in your `$watchCollection` to get the value.

```
$scope.$watchCollection('settings',
  function() {
    for (i = 0; i < $scope.settings['accounts'].length; i++) {
      $scope.getBalance($scope.settings['accounts'][i])
        .then(bal => console.log(bal));
    }
  }
);

$scope.getBalance = function(addr) {
  if ($scope.settings.contract !== null) {
    return $scope.settings.contract.deployed().then(function(deployed) {
      return deployed.balanceOf(addr);
    }).then(function(res) {
       balance = res.toNumber();
       console.log(balance);
       return balance;
    }).catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err.message);
    });
  }

  return Promise.resolve(null);
};
```

Note, in functions that return `Promises`, make sure all pathways return a `Promise` or bad things will happen (hence the `Promise.resolve(null)`).